# C# - Looping through object parameter that was passed from new thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, object, foreach

I am trying to start a new thread and pass an argument to one of my methods.  The argument is a `List<string>` and contains about 20 string items.  I can pass the array fine using the following code:

```
List<string> strList = new List<string>();

Thread newThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Class.Method));
newThread.Start(strList);
```

My Method is defined as:

```
public void Method(object strList)
{
//code
}
```

My question then is how can I run a foreach loop through each string that is contained in this object?

Comment: Is it a string array or a `List<string>`? They're not the same...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Three options:

- Use `ParameterizedThreadStart` as you are, and cast within the method:

  ```
  public void Method(object strList)
  {
      List<string> list = (List<string>) strList;
      // Use list here
  }
  ```
- Use an anonymous function to capture the variable in a strongly typed way, and call a strongly-typed method from the anonymous function:

  ```
  List<string> strList = new List<string>();
  ThreadStart action = () => Method(strList);
  new Thread(action).Start();

  ...

  public void Method(List<string> list)
  {
      // Use list here
  }
  ```
- Use a higher-level abstraction such as the Task Parallel Library or Parallel LINQ instead; depending on what you're doing, this may make things simpler.

If you *do* want to start a new thread, I'd use the second approach - keep the "dirtiness" localized to the method starting a new thread. Any of these approaches will work though. Note that if you had *more than one* piece of information to pass to the new thread, the second approach ends up being simpler than creating a `Tuple` and unpacking it.

Comment: Using an anonymous method in order to strong type like this..that's neat, had never occurred to me before!

Comment: Perfect!  I actually had figured out the first method shortly after I posted but am opting to go with option #2 and it works great.  thanks!

Comment: Just to expand on this on a little because Im curious.  Is there a way to get the count using strList.Count and create a new thread for each item in the list?

Comment: @Ron: That's where Parallel LINQ would come into play - `Parallel.ForEach`.

Comment: Ok, I may look into that in the future as I would have to upgrade my software.  Thanks

Comment: @Ron: Just realized that Parallel.ForEach probably doesn't count as Parallel LINQ - although both could be applicable here. Anyway, the funky stuff which was introduced in .NET 4 :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to typecast the `object` to your list type like e.g. the following:

```
public void Method(object strList)
{
    var list = (List<string>)strList;
    foreach ( var s in list )
    {
        // Do something.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to cast the object to it's actual type, then you can just use foreach.

Answer (score 0):

Cast your object with `(List<string>`) and then use the iteration through it

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) // Loop through List with for
        {
            Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
        }
```

Comment: You should put ticks around the `List<string>` cast then it'll show up as code.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to cast it back to a list of strings like so:

```
public void Method(object strList)
{
    List<string> internalStringList = strList as List<string>;
    //this is a save cast the "internalStringList" variable will 
    //be null if the cast fails.
}
```

You can also do this:

```
List<string> internalStringList = (List<string>) strList;
```

but this could throw an `InvalidCastException` if strList isn't a List

Answer (score 0):

To be safe:

```
public void Method(object strList)
{
   var list = strList as List<string>;
   if (list != null)
    { 
       foreach(var item in list )
       {
          //code here
       }
    }
}
```